# Olympus Camera Kit: How to avoid the rotation of live view?

Tags: ios, olympus-camerakit

I'd rather not to rotate live view image even if the camera rotates as the sample source code ImageCaptureSample does. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find `camera:didUpdateLiveView:metadata:` method in `LiveViewController`. Camera Kit sends your app metadata with camera orientation tag through this method. ImageCaptureSample converts coordinate system using metadata in `OLYCameraConvertDataToImage` utility. Why don't you overwrite the orientation tag to "1" whenever the camera rotates to any direction? Hope this works out.

Here is a sample code:

```
- (void)camera:(OLYCamera *)camera didUpdateLiveView:(NSData *)data metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpMetadata = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:metadata];
    // 1 means orientation is 0 degree.
    tmpMetadata[@"Orientation"] = @"1";
    UIImage *image = OLYCameraConvertDataToImage(data, tmpMetadata);
    // UIImage *image = OLYCameraConvertDataToImage(data, metadata);

    self.imageView.image = nil;
    self.imageView.image = image;
}
```